# Obtener variable de un Activity

Tags: java, android-studio, sms

Tengo dos clases, una Localizacion y una SMS.
La clase Localizacion me proporciona latitud y longitud y la direccion al momento de ejecutarse.

Quiero pasar esa informacion a la clase SMS y que lo agrege al texto del mensaje.

EL problema es que me devuelve null... ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?
gracias

CLASE LOCALIZACION:

```
//OBTENER DIRECCION
try {
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> list = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitudeGPS, longitudeGPS, 1);
                    if (!list.isEmpty()) {
                        Address DirCalle = list.get(0);
                        String direccion = DirCalle.getAddressLine(0);
                        direccionCompleta = "Estoy en "+direccion+"(Coordenadas: LON "+longitudeGPS+" /LAT "+latitudeGPS+")";
                        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDireccion)).setText(direccionCompleta);
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        //METODO QUE ENVIE LA UBICACION
        public  String getLocalizacion(){
            return direccionCompleta;
        }
    }
```

CLASE SMS

```
public class SMS extends AppCompatActivity {
    String movil;
    String localizacion;
    String mensaje = "Hola. ";

    //obtener numero telefono
    public void escogerContacto(){
        movil="111111111";
    }

    public void direccion(){
        Localizacion Localizacion = new Localizacion();
        localizacion = Localizacion.getLocalizacion();
        mensaje=mensaje + localizacion;
    }

    public void SMS(){
        try{
            escogerContacto();
            direccion();
            SmsManager smgr = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smgr.sendTextMessage(movil,null,mensaje,null,null);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            //Toast.makeText(SMS.this, "SMS Failed to Send, Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Has comprobado que la aplicación pase antes por la obtención de la localización? Parece ser que se ejecuta antes el enviar mensaje que la obtención de la localización.

Comment: El "problema" es que la localizacion es una Activity, y abre la ventana pero no coge los parametros

Comment: Hola... ehm la "clase" LOCALIZACION no se ve como una clase, podrias poner bien el codigo por favor? Porque por lo poco que pusiste nunca estas ejecutando el geocoder que carga la lista. Ademas si Localizacion es un Activity, no podes esperar instanciarlo y que funcione. Deberias abrirlo con startActivityForResult() o algo asi.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que comunmente se realiza es modificar el constructor de la clase SMS para que reciba este valor y puedas usarlo aquí:

```
public void direccion(String localizacion){
    Localizacion Localizacion = new Localizacion();
    //localizacion = Localizacion.getLocalizacion();
    this.localizacion = localizacion; //Recibe valor.
    mensaje=mensaje + localizacion;
}
```

por lo tanto al inicializar la clase SMS puedes enviar el valor desde la clase Localizacion :

```
 SMS claseSms = new SMS(localizacion);
```